# Can the same ViewController.view be added as subview to different views as a Singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

My app has a search view(search bar) which is used all over the app. I don't want to create duplicated code so I created a view controller called MySearchViewController to handle the search job, then I created a singleton object in AppDelegate. In every view controller, I added my search view like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   MySearchViewController* search = [AppDelegate searchViewController];
   [self.view addSubView:search.view];
}
```

My questions, Is it a good way? It's a singleton so it can be added to many views. Do I need to remove the view from last view before adding to current view?

Comment: You can find "Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview." in `addSubview` of `UIView` class reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that you are mixing some concepts that are not necessarily related: avoid duplicated code and Singletons.

Wikipedia says this about singletons:

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. The concept is sometimes generalized to systems that operate more efficiently when only one object exists, or that restrict the instantiation to a certain number of objects. The term comes from the mathematical concept of a singleton.

The most important characteristic of a singleton (in my humble opinion) is that the object is instantiated only once and every single place in your application will use the same instance. Well, to use your search feature everywhere and avoid duplicated code you don't need the search view to be instantiated only once, maybe the data that comes with it, **but not the view itself**.

Two better ways of achieving this:

1 - You can create a ViewController with your search and just embed this on the other views using a Container View, you can use blocks or a delegate protocol to communicate between your controller and the view that is embedding it.

2 - You can create a Parent class of the ViewController that will include the search bar, like a SearchViewController and all the other viewControllers that needs the same feature will inherit from it.

The singleton could be useful if you are planing to share the same search data and text between all the ViewControllers of the application, but it would be a singleton only with these information, the UISearchBar and all other view elements should not be part of the singleton.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the singleton because the search view has many search conditions, when the user select some conditions(for example, male/female), and then jump to the other view, I want the conditions to be kept.

Comment: So use the singleton to keep the conditions, in an array, dictionary, strings, etc. But not the views

Comment: I had considered using a base class,  but I don't want to make the base class become too large.

Comment: Why the views can not be instantiated only once? It's just a principle or it will cause some issue?

Comment: you can instantiate a view only once, of course.. but one instance of a view can't have different superviews at the same time..

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should instantiate a fresh instance of MySearchViewController every time when you want to add it to another view to avoid problems.

**Do I need to remove the view from last view before adding to current view?**

Its not required to remove it from previous super view because whenever you add this singleton MySearchViewController's view to some other view, it will automatically gets removed from last super view and now its super view is your new view where you have added it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a view from a different view controller, your view controller has to be that view controller's parent view controller:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   MySearchViewController* search = [AppDelegate searchViewController];
   [self addChildViewController:search];
   [self.view addSubView:search.view];
}
```

also, make sure that when the search.view is added, it is already initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use NSObject class ?, i do not know your requirement , but if you want to store latest updated value in whole project(in execution) then you should use the singleton, but if you do not want to store value (i mean one result for whole project) then you should use NSObject derived Class. advantage is singleton consumes memory so memory will be wasted. NSObject class will be reusable and only allocated when it is required and then ARC will take care of all things. If you want to know how to create NSObject and use of it then you can give me reply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to load a XIB as part of a custom object with the object gets initialized.

Why are you not creating custom search component for search?

you can use this component all over the app.
also this is not creating duplicat code.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
        self.frame = self.view.frame;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. Hope this is work for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   if ([self.view viewWithTag:123456]) {
       [[self.view viewWithTag:123456] removeFromSuperview];
   }

    MySearchViewController* search = [AppDelegate searchViewController];
    search.view.tag = 123456; // give a any random tag to view
    [self.view addSubView:search.view];
    [self addChildViewController:search];
}
```

Please make sure given tag is not assign to other object except search.view in self.view.

Thanks